# How to Refer create_resource in puppet like we do for File[""], Service[""], Package[""], etc

Tags: puppet

I have a puppet file with an `exec` resource and `create_resources` function. I want `create_resources` to be executed right after the `exec` resource. How do I do this?

Similar to referencing `File['name']`, I tried `Create_Resources[....]` with `notify`, but it is not working.

```
notify => Create_Resources[domain_ip_map, $data, $baseconfigdir].
```

**init.pp**

```
exec { 'purge-config-files':
  before  => [File["${config_file_service}"], File["${config_file_host}"]],
  command => "/bin/rm -f ${baseconfigdir}/*",
  #notify => Create_Resources[domain_ip_map, $data, $baseconfigdir],
}

create_resources(domain_ip_map, $data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the dependency metaparameters `require`, `before`, `subscribe`, and `notify`, the attributes must be resource types. Specifying `notify => Create_Resources[domain_ip_map, $data, $baseconfigdir],` means you are attempting to specify the output of the `create_resources` function as the resources. That is not going to be an acceptable type for that parameter.

There are two different ways to go about this. You can either add a `notify` or a `subscribe`.

With the `subscribe`, you would need to add:

```
subscribe => Exec['purge-config-files'],
```

everywhere necessary into the `$data` hash that contains your `domain_ip_map` resources' parameters and attributes.

With the notify, you would need to assemble the array of resource titles like the following (assuming using `stdlib`):

```
$domain_ip_map_titles = keys($data)
```

and then put that in your `exec` resource instead like this:

```
exec { 'purge-config-files':
  before  => [File["${config_file_service}"], File["${config_file_host}"]],
  command => "/bin/rm -f ${baseconfigdir}/*",
  notify  => Domain_ip_map[$domain_ip_map_titles],
}

create_resources(domain_ip_map, $data)
```

Either of those will work for your situation.

Comment: create resource creates macro for each elements of that array right ??, and notify notifies all macros at once ?

Comment: I have one more problem with this script. Lets say we have 10 elements in that $data array, and I need to restart nagios service after creating all 10 services and hosts in the appropriate configuration files. How to make sure that the service restarts only after executing all 10 Domain_ip_map ???

Comment: Same as above except use a `subscribe` instead of a `notify` because the relationship is reversed. So inside of your nagios `service` resource you would have a `subscribe => Domain_ip_map[$domain_ip_map_titles],`.

Comment: If I subscribe like that, wouldn't that restarts nagios service 10 times in a row ???..

Comment: I just started learning puppet and I'm still slightly confused with create resources.  Are you sure that the way you mention subscribe applies only to the definition as a whole and not to each element of the hash